# Update statement working in SQLite Browser not in java with the exact same syntax

Tags: java, sqlite

Okay I executed the same code thats in the update query in the SQLite db browser and it worked successfully

```
public void StatusUpdate(ActionEvent event) {   

    try {

        String test = null;
        test = txtEditStatus.getText();
        System.out.println(test);

        String query = "UPDATE member SET desc = ? WHERE username = ?";
          PreparedStatement preparedStmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
          preparedStmt.setString   (1, test);
          preparedStmt.setString(2, "Custom Hue");

          // execute the java preparedstatement
          preparedStmt.executeUpdate();

          connection.close();



    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

However when running eclipse with JFx, it prints what I type in the console but doesnt update in the db, anyone know why?

For the user asking about the connection:

```
Connection connection;

public ProfileController() {
    connection = SQLConnection.Connector();
    if (connection == null)
        System.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Do you have auto commit turned off?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Dude I've sat 45 minutes flat out wondering wtf, I have been connected to a db, just the wrong one -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check that your connection is actually connected to the correct database.
are you sure you have the right connection string set up?

you should do an output on your exception handler, what if there is an exception?

are you sure the connection is open?
are you sure the user exists in the database and table you are trying to update?
try doing a read first, to see if you have an open connection. Print your exception, just in case, never leave it blank. That's just bad practice.

How about you try a

```
  preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
  connection.commit(); 
  connection.close();
```

Just incase autocommit isn't enabled?

Comment: Check updated Q at the bottom, no connection would = program crash

Comment: Dude I've sat 45 minutes flat out wondering wtf, I have been connected to a db, just the wrong one -_-

Comment: @Foxhound please do the following:
Print out your connection string, so you are 100% sure you are connected to the correct database.
Then Include a read from the database prior to the update. So you are sure the table you are attempting to update, exists, with the rows you are attempting to update.

try a: 
Connection.commit();

If you haven't already. 

If none of this works, or doesn't yield an idea, I have no idea what is going on.